# How can I release and renew my DHCP lease from Terminal?

Tags: network

From the Terminal, how can I release and renew my DHCP lease?

Currently, I'm doing the following for the wireless interface, but I'm wondering if there's a better way:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig en1 up
```

For the wired interface, replace `en1` with `en0`.

Comment: Are you waiting for someone to say, no - there is no better way or can we address your question / edit it so it's likely to get a different answer than ue `ipconfig`/`ifconfig`?

Answer (score 29):

This can also be achieved with the following two commands :

```
sudo ipconfig set en0 BOOTP
sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP
```

You can alias the two together in your bash profile:

```
alias renew="sudo ipconfig set en0 BOOTP && sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP"
```

So then you just have one command called `renew` that will release and renew your DHCP.

Comment: Rob's answer will certainly work - but `ipconfig set` always first de-configures the interface before setting up DHCP again. I've never needed the first command - and `ipconfig` is much more high level (it handles routes better) than `ifconfig` and I prefer it for the case you state.

Comment: The cli command "ipconfig set en0 DHCP" is not a dhcp-renew in the pure sense but a complete discover,offer,request,ack procedure. The "renew" button on the control pane just generates a dhcp-request (preceded by a release) and is answered by an ACK. There is a difference between both as renew is typically sent by a cpe at half the lease time to renew to lease before it expires. Internet access-devices like a cable modem termination system will react differently on both procedure.
So I'm still looking for a pure dhcp-renew command

Comment: @robzolkos Above command run perfectly fine for the Admin account but when I logged in as a standard user in MAC It prompts for password. If possible how I could skip this password part and a standard user can run this command.

Answer (score 11):

The way the renew button works in System Preferences is to create a key in the system configuration. One can create the key via:

```
echo "add State:/Network/Interface/en0/RefreshConfiguration temporary" | sudo scutil
```

Swapping `en0` for the desired interface.